# Automatically Capitalise i to I

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to automatically capitalise `i` when writing in org-mode?  I have to manually search all `i` and replaced it with `I`, before exporting to PDF. I want to do this only for the English word `I`, not occurrences of the letter `i` that may appear within words.

Comment: Do you really want to replace *all* occurrences of the *letter* `i` with `I`? Or do you only want to replace `i` with `I` if it represents the English *word* `I` (personal pronoun)? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Hi, only to replace the English word `I`.

Comment: I thought so :) You can use the code in my answer to tell Emacs to do this for you. Just add it to your init-file.

Comment: wow. that's quick. thanks, will have a try soon.

Comment: You could define an abbreviation: `C-x a g` when the point is after `I`. Answer the prompt with `i`. Enable abbrevs mode if not already enabled: `M-x abbrevs-mode`. Now every time you will type `<not a word constituent>i<not a word constituent>`, it will be replaced by `I`.

Comment: @wvxvw This will have better visibility as an answer.

Comment: @T.Verron oh, I see Biggy Smalls already wrote that :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replacing the word `i` with the word `I` is a job for [abbrevs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Abbrevs.html). It activates after you press the space bar.

*However...*

Sometimes you do **not** want `i` replaced with `I`, such as when typing `i = i + 1` in some programming language, but you do want it to expand when typing comments and strings.

In the case of `org-mode` you want to expand `i` in normal text, suppress the expansion in `src` blocks, *except* when in a comment or string within a `src` block.

Here's some code to do that:

```el
(defun my-text-abbrev-expand-p ()
  "Return t if the abbrev is in a text context, which is: in
 comments and strings only when in a prog-mode derived-mode or
 src block in org-mode, and anywhere else."
  (if (or (derived-mode-p 'prog-mode)
          (and (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
               (org-in-src-block-p 'inside)))
      (nth 8 (syntax-ppss))
    t))

(define-abbrev-table 'my-text-abbrev-table ()
  "Abbrev table for text-only abbrevs. Expands only in comments and strings."
  :enable-function #'my-text-abbrev-expand-p)

(dolist (table (list text-mode-abbrev-table
                     prog-mode-abbrev-table))
  (abbrev-table-put table
                    :parents (list my-text-abbrev-table)))

;; Bug fix for python and lisp modes who's abbrev tables aren't set up correctly:

(eval-after-load "python"
  (abbrev-table-put python-mode-abbrev-table
                    :parents (list my-text-abbrev-table
                                   python-mode-skeleton-abbrev-table)))

(eval-after-load "lisp-mode"
  (abbrev-table-put lisp-mode-abbrev-table
                    :parents (list my-text-abbrev-table)))

;; Our only expansion, so far...

(define-abbrev my-text-abbrev-table "i" "I" nil :system t)
```

If you happen to manage your `init.el` [as an org file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3143/can-i-use-org-mode-to-structure-my-emacs-or-other-el-configuration-file/3146) you may be interested in the following snippet of additional code to manage your text expansions:

```
#+NAME: my-text-abbrevs
- i: I
- teh: the


#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var my-text-abbrevs=my-text-abbrevs

;; ...code from above goes here goes here...

(defun my-text-abbrev-table-init (abbrevs-org-list)
  "Parse 'name: expansion' pairs from an org list and insert into abbrev table."
  (message "Creating text-abbrev table...")
  (dolist (abbrev abbrevs-org-list)
    (let* ((pair (split-string abbrev ": +" :omit-nuls " "))
           (name (nth 0 pair))
           (expansion (nth 1 pair)))
      (define-abbrev my-text-abbrev-table name expansion nil :system t))))

(my-text-abbrev-table-init my-text-abbrevs)

#+end_src
```

Use your normal text editing and org skills to manage a list of expansion words. If it gets too long you can use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to collapse or hide it in a sub-heading.

FYI: If you wanted to do the *opposite* and expand text only in a program context and not in a text context then Emacs already has you covered with the `expand` package. For example, you could have `if` expand to `if (...) {...}` with a template which would otherwise be annoying when writing comments.

The `expand` package is not mentioned in the Emacs manual.

Comment: looks great but I can't test the functions.  what is the definition of `my-eval-after-load`?

Comment: `:omit-nuls`, do you mean `:omit-nulls`?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want to capitalize `i` if it represents the English word "I" (personal pronoun), the following code will do what you want:

```el
(defun capitalize-i ()
  (when (and (eq major-mode 'org-mode) (looking-back " i "))
    (capitalize-word -1)))

(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook 'capitalize-i)
```

If you want to replace *all* occurrences of `i` with `I`, change `(looking-back " i ")` to `(looking-back "i")` in the code above.

---

If the solution above turns out to noticeably affect performance, you can instead tell Emacs to replace `i` with `I` every time you save your `.org` file (as suggested by @kaushalmodi in the comments):

```el
(defun capitalize-i ()
  (when (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
    (replace-regexp "i" "I" t (point-min) (point-max))))

(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'capitalize-i)
```

Note that the third argument to `replace-regexp` (set to `t`) specifies that Emacs should

> replace only matches surrounded by word boundaries.

So we don't have to specify a more complex regexp (such as `\s-i\s-`) here.

Comment: I am worried about the performance hit as emacs will be trying to check if the previous few characters were " i " while the user types each new character. I refrain from using `post-self-insert-hook` and especially when one usually types a lot in a mode like this. Suggestion: Would replacing i to I in a buffer wide search of `^i\s-` or `\s-i\s-` be more efficient in a `before-save-hook`?

Comment: @kaushalmodi Probably :) The code above was simply the first thing that popped into my head when I read the question. Would you mind if I added some code that implements your suggestion to my answer?

Comment: Sure, not a problem. Go ahead :)

Comment: @kaushalmodi, @itsjeyd, thank you very much for your answer and consideration. It works very well with the main body, but 1) it will change `i` in the src block, 2) will change the `i` in italic, bold or inline code style.  3) will change /i/ to /I/, resulting invalid links.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use auto-capitalize package ([github page](https://github.com/yuutayamada/auto-capitalize-el)), which can do everything for you, not just i to I.

```el
(require 'auto-capitalize)
(auto-capitalize-mode 1)
```

And give you a bonus: You can turn off auto-capitalize when cursor is at source block, and turn on it at other place using snippet below, which is from [John Kitchin's blog](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2014/12/03/Selective-auto-capitalization-in-org-buffers/).

Added: if want to escape /+something/, just need to add a another condition, like `(looking-back "\\/[A-Za-z]+")`.

```
(defun exempt-auto-capitalize ()
  (if (or (looking-back "\\/[A-Za-z]+") (org-in-block-p '("src")))
      (when auto-capitalize
        (auto-capitalize-mode -1))
    (unless auto-capitalize
      (auto-capitalize-mode 1))))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'exempt-auto-capitalize)
```

Cheers! Please give your thanks to these two kind people.

Comment: great to have it skip the src blocks. how difficulty to have it skip the /i/, *i* and links?

Comment: @yi.tang.uni Add a condition that tell auto-capitalize to stop when cursor is at word '\i', please confirm the answer.

Comment: @yi.tang.uni, sorry for code just now. Some bugs there, has been fixed.