# Evil equivalent of imap

Tags: evil

How do I make `ae` in evil insert mode produce `æ`?
This would be the equivalent of `inoremap ae æ` in vim.
(I tried
`(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "ae") (kbd "\C-kae"))`,
but after this typing `a` (without an `e` after it) didn't 
produce an `a`, but rather the error `a is undefined`.)

Comment: Not a very clear question, IMO. Why don't you describe ("specify") just what you are trying to do and just what you tried and just what you saw from your trial and just what you expected to see instead?

Comment: Maybe `(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "ae") "æ")`?

Comment: @npostavs, no, that stills ruins the bare "a".

Comment: This is probably more of a job for [`abbrev-mode`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode) than for a function.  See, for example, http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/automatically-capitalise-i-to-i.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like

```
(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook
          (lambda ()
            (and (eq last-command-event ?e)
                 (looking-back "ae" (- (point) 2))
                 (replace-match "æ"))))
```

Comment: Thanks! there is no timeout on this. how would I escape to produce 'ae'?

Comment: You can use `a C-q e`.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at the `key-chord` emacs package. it allows you to define mappings of multiple keys and take action on them. in your case the action would just be `(insert "æ")`.

alternatively, insert a digraph by typing `C-k a e` in evil's insert mode. this invokes `(evil-insert-digraph)` and reads `a` and `e`, then produces æ.

Comment: `C-k` doesn't give me any digraph here.  Could you explain what you mean?  Is that part of the key-chord package.

Comment: part of evil, works only in insert state