# Insert space before link with org-insert-link

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, doom, insert

In Doom Emacs and org-mode, I want to use `org-insert-link` pressing the minimum amount of keys.
So I want to combine two-four commands in one.
The default behaviour doesn't leave space before or after.

I have tried various variations of the following but it doesn't work:

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-mode 'org-insert-link-with-space)
(defun org-insert-link-with-space ()
       "org-insert-link-with-space, like org-insert-link but after prompt"
       (interactive)
       (insert " ") (org-insert-link) (insert " ") (evil-insert-state)
)
(map! :ne "SPC m l" #'org-insert-link-with-space)
```

I want to type this:

here is a **link** for you

pressing the minimum amount of keys:

here<kbd>Space</kbd>is<kbd>Space</kbd>a<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>mll<copy/paste link and description description><kbd>Ret</kbd>for<kbd>Space</kbd>you

How do I fix my snippet?

---

Update: I combined three answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330731/elisp-how-to-execute-several-expressions-in-else-block), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800134/calling-interactive-functions-sequentially-in-emacs) and [3](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24573/evil-equivalent-of-imap)) from SE and ended up to what I currently use. It inserts a link like ViM's `inoremap` by pressing jk only while in insert-mode:

```lisp
(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook
          (lambda ()
            (and (eq last-command-event ?k)
                 (looking-back "jk" (- (point) 2))
                 (if (> 1 2)
                   (message "True")
                 (call-interactively 'evil-delete-backward-char)
                 (call-interactively 'evil-delete-backward-char)
                 (call-interactively 'org-insert-link)
                 ))))
```

[image: Insert link in insert-mode with "jk", like inoremap in ViM]
It certainly needs some refinement, but for the time being it works perfectly!

Comment: I don't know how to map with `map!` in doom, but you should not `(add-hook 'org-mode 'org-insert-link-with-space)`

Comment: Three questions: 1) if you call your function interactively, M-x org-insert-link-with-space, does it does it do what you?  2) is this the behavior you want all the time? 3) do you already have a convenient key binding to insert a link?

Comment: @TianshuWang you are right, `add-hook` doesn't alter anything

Comment: @JohnKitchin Thanks for your comment! 1. Almost. It does let spaces but skips the description. So, I get `here is a http://stackexchange.com for you` 2. Not very sure at the moment. 3. With the help of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24573/evil-equivalent-of-imap I'm trying to insert a link without leaving insert-mode, so without a keybinding being necessary and also saving extra key presses. It feels like I'm half-way through - when I wrote the question I was about ~30% towards my end goal. I really need to sit down and learn some elisp, because programming my editor worths it!

Comment: Why not just use an abbrev for jk?

Comment: @JohnKitchin It could be, but it saves some space keystrokes. In some documents, I want links inside parentheses as here: " (link) " and in some of my notes I like leading the link providing a short description, but I didn't want to make the question too complicated. Now I have two ways to create functions which run other functions sequentially: advising and the unrefined way I found out and I'm happy with both of them. (note that I'm basically elisp illiterate)

Comment: @JohnKitchin Yes, https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode#:~:text=Emacs%20has%20a%20nice%20feature,this%20case%20'Your%20Name'. worths some exploration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this all the time, and are happy with your keybinding for inserting a link, you can use an advice for this. I am not familiar with evil/doom, you may also need `(evil-insert-state)` at the end of the function.

```
(defun org-insert-link-with-space (orig-func &rest args)
  (insert " ")
  (call-interactively orig-func)
  (insert " "))
  
(advice-add 'org-insert-link :around  #'org-insert-link-with-space)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It does exactly what I asked. Advising functions will be very helpful for sure. What you proposed works perfectly and does exactly what I want (with `evil-insert-state` in the end). I figured out an even faster way to insert links and I updated my question.