# How to implement comments outline in ESS similar to that of Rstudio?

Tags: ess, comment, r

Shifting from Rstudio to ESS took some time with me because of the steep learning curve of a versatile Emacs editor, but is was a worthwhile experience. What I am still missing in ESS is that outline or overview of the R script file based on comments (called sections in Rstudio) by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+R` to give `# some comments or title here` (see the screenshot).

[image]

After having a lot of sections and the file size becomes very large, it becomes increasingly difficult to navigate throughout a giant multi-section file. In Rstudio I press that orange button `#` to pop up a small window of all sections or `#` comments and by **clicking** any one of them will put me on that heading in the file.

Similar thing I found in AUCTeX is the `C-c =` which will show an outline clickable table to navigate that `.tex` file.

How to obtain this handy overview in ESS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like `orgstruct-mode`.  In the following file you can collapse headings with `Tab` or `S-Tab`, much like in `org-mode`.  Note that the `eval` part below collapsed the file to out-most level when opening the file.

```
##* sec1
x <- rnorm(10)
##** sec11
y <- x<0
##* sec 2
z <- x + y

## Local Variables:
## outline-regexp: "##*\\*+\\|\\`"
## orgstruct-heading-prefix-regexp: "##*\\*+\\|\\`"
## eval: (progn (orgstruct-mode) (org-global-cycle 3))
## End:
```

Comment: Great! even more flexible! but do you know how to activate/deactivate application of `orstruct` code while I am inside the buffer? to play with the code I have to kill/and open the same buffer and answer y or no for application of the safe code.

Comment: The first part of regexp till `\\|` will detect the `##` and multiples of following asterisks, but I wonder what is the benefit of the last part `|\\\`` in regexp?

Comment: do `revert-file` will reload file-local variables.  There's a info page about if you search (I haven't got time atm).  The `\\`` matches the beginning of the buffer/string depending on context.

Comment: is there any way to add a directive like in `org-mode` to determine level of folding for this buffer, `#+STARTUP: overview` kind of thing?

Comment: doctorate, you could try different arguments ("levels") in the `org-global-cycle` call.

Comment: could you please suggest one which is compatible with `#+STARTUP: overview` directive?