# Can I use org-mode to structure other dotfiles?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I really like the idea of structuring my `init.el` file with orgmode. Now I wonder if this would also work with other configuration files like `vimrc`.

Comment: Just use `orgstruct-mode` or `orgstruct++-mode`.  See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8056/how-to-implement-comments-outline-in-ess-similar-to-that-of-rstudio/8065#8065

Answer (score 1):

If you mean via Org's [tangle features](http://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-source-code.html) then yes, it lets you tangle out arbitrary files, and will even syntax highlight them if you have the proper major-modes installed.

As an example, [my dotfiles repo](http://fort.kickass.systems:10082/cgit/personal/rrix/pub/fsem.git/tree/fsem.org) contains a single Org file that tangles out to all of my configurations and looks darn nice when exported.

Comment: Since I can't leave more link comments since I signed up to reply to you, another option is [lentic.el](https://github.com/phillord/lentic)