# Generate different markup for not-tangled code blocks in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel, literate-programming

Is there a way in org-mode's HTML export to make it so that code blocks that have `:tangle no` will appear differently? Even adding a different HTML class will do, as one can then probably add some CSS to alter their appearance (e.g. grey background or whatever).

---

Longer version / context:

I'm using `org-mode` (and its `org-babel`) to keep code and documentation together in a single file. Specifically, [as in this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3143/can-i-use-org-mode-to-structure-my-emacs-or-other-el-configuration-file), I have

```
(require 'org)
(org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name "~/emacs/config/init.org"))
```

so that `init.org` can generate both an `init.el` file (for consumption by Emacs), and an `init.html` file (for consumption by me, when I want to make sense of my config again). In this file, I have some sections that I don't want to be part of `init.el` (e.g. either I decided against them, or they're simplified versions given first for understanding, before the “real” code, etc). For them, instead of something like

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(require 'cc-mode)
#+END_SRC
```

I have:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle no
(require 'cc-mode)
#END_SRC
```

and everything works fine: the code no longer runs on startup, as it's no longer part of the generated `init.el`. However, the code still shows up in `init.html` (as I want it to) when I export from the org file, but unfortunately there's no longer any indication that this section is not going be tangled.

I imagine that in the HTML file, instead of

```
<div class="org-src-container">
  <pre class="src src-emacs-lisp">
    ...
  </pre>
</div>
```

if I could persuade org-mode / org-babel export to add another class, then I'd know how to solve the rest.

Comment: Looks like one would have to edit `org-html-src-block` (in `ox-html.el`). Not sure how to tell it that something is a `:tangle no` block... maybe it's already present in `src-block`, or can be passed in `info` (wherever this function is called... not sure of that either).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `:around` [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) for `org-html-src-block` to wrap the code block generated by `org-html-src-block` with your own html block, e.g.: `<div style="background-color:lightgray">`.

But there is a little subtlety. The argument `src-block` of `org-html-src-block` is not really the parse tree of the original buffer.
In the process of copying, parsing and reprinting that precedes the export the function `org-babel-exp-src-block` removes by default the source block argument `:tangle no`.
To avoid that you need to add `%tangle` to the format fields of `org-babel-exp-code-template`.

There follows a minimal example code:

```el
(defun my-org-html-src-block-no-tangle (oldfun src-block contents info)
  "Wrap source blocks with :tangle==no with colored background."
  (let* ((old-ret (funcall oldfun src-block contents info))
     (pars (org-babel-parse-header-arguments (org-element-property :parameters src-block)))
     (tangle (cdr (assoc :tangle pars))))
    (if (assoc-string tangle '(no))
    (concat
     "<div style=\"background-color:lightgray;\">"
     old-ret
     "</div>")
      old-ret)))

(advice-add 'org-html-src-block :around #'my-org-html-src-block-no-tangle)

(setq org-babel-exp-code-template "#+BEGIN_SRC %lang :tangle "no"
%body
#+END_SRC")
```

Tested with:

```
GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.28) of 2018-05-28
```

and the following org fragment:

```
There follows a minimal example code:

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle no :export both
(defun my-org-html-src-block-no-tangle (oldfun src-block contents info)
  "Wrap source blocks with :tangle==no with colored background."
  (let* ((old-ret (funcall oldfun src-block contents info))
     (pars (org-babel-parse-header-arguments (org-element-property :parameters src-block)))
     (tangle (cdr (assoc :tangle pars))))
    (if (assoc-string tangle '(no))
    (concat
     "<div style=\"background-color:lightgray;\">"
     old-ret
     "</div>")
      old-ret)))

(advice-add 'org-html-src-block :around #'my-org-html-src-block-no-tangle)

(setq org-babel-exp-code-template "#+BEGIN_SRC %lang%switches%flags :tangle %tangle
%body
,#+END_SRC")

#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle t
(message "Hurrah!")
#+END_SRC
```

Test result:

[image: Render source blocks with :tangle no different from that ones with :tangle t]

Notes:

- An alternative (maybe better) approach would be to derive a new exporter with `org-export-define-derived-backend` from `'html`. The only function you would overwrite would be `org-html-export-src-block` and you could use the original version there.
- You could also set `org-babel-exp-code-template` buffer-locally in your `settings.org`.
- You don't need to add `:tangle yes` to each of the source blocks you want to tangle. You can just add the following line to the top of your `settings.org`:
  `#+PROPERTY: header-args :tangle yes`

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Note my last comment (at the bottom) about `header-args`.

Comment: That works, thanks again... Nice work!