# org-agenda-file-to-front, when in Literate Configuration

Tags: org-agenda

I use a literate configuration, so my init.el file gets overwritten every time I tangle; how does this play together with org-agenda-file-to-front?;)

Maybe add a separate file to hold the included org files?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `org-agenda-file-to-front` but instead of tangling from your org file, you could put the following code in your `.emacs`. Where PATH is the path to your org file.

```
(require 'org)
(org-babel-load-file "PATH")
```

Read [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3143/can-i-use-org-mode-to-structure-my-emacs-or-other-el-configuration-file) for more details.

Comment: I used to do that, but I'd rather tangle externally, because then emacs starts up with an .el file that I can debug. With org-babel-load-file, it's impossible for it to say which line it has trouble with.

Comment: Of, course, maybe a solution is to tangle to another file, then keep init.el, so that it can write that information there.

Comment: To debug/test, you can use another Emacs instance with `emacs -q -l PATH/init.el`